# My code cannot find my static methods when pressing F11

Tags: c#, enums, static, sms

I have a static class which got methods which hold text to send. On my business logic when in am debugging and press F11 to debug the class. It is giving the error below. What am I missing?

Method not found: `System.String info.Notifications.AppointmentBookedText(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`.

Class.

```
   public static class Notifications
   {
      public enum SmsTypeCatergory
      {
          AppointmentCreated = 1,
      }
   }

public static string AppointmentBookedText(int claimId, int day, int month, int year, int time)
{
    string Text = "Your doctor's appointment has been booked for " + day + " " + month + " " + year + " " + time + ".";
    return Text;
}
```

Bussiness Logic

```
    public void SMSConfirmation(int SmsTypeId)
    {
        switch (SmsTypeId)
        {

            case (int)Notifications.SmsTypeCatergory.AppointmentCreated:
                Notifications.SendSMSSingle(this.Cellnumber, Notifications.AppointmentBookedText(this.day, Convert.ToInt32(this.month.ToString()), this.year, Convert.ToInt32(this.time.ToString())));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That method is not inside a class, format your code and you will see...

Comment: Methods need to be placed inside of classes.  Surely that's not the *only* compiler error you're seeing.

Comment: public static string method is inside the public static class Notifications. and when i took it out of the class i get namespace error. what must i do?

Comment: The code  you posted above shows the method _outside_ the class definition.  If that is not how the code is written, please edit your question and fix the code so that it matches what you really have.